# Installing dia on macports: invalid command name "post-deactivate"

Tags: macos, diagram, macports, dia

I'm trying to install dia on Mac OSX, but I get an odd error: `invalid command name "post-deactivate"`

```
$ sudo port install -d dia
--->  Computing dependencies for diaError: Unable to execute port: invalid command name "post-deactivate"
Before reporting a bug, first run the command again with the -d flag to get complete output.
```

I can't find anything helpful about this error from Googling. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in the Portfile of one of dia's dependencies. If you haven't updated your ports lately, run

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
```

to get the latest version of MacPorts (the relevant Portfile may have been fixed). If that doesn't work, [file a bug](http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets).